# How to fix r=g compilation issue in Java?

Tags: java

Fr the following generic class, there is a compilation error for the line r=g:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from GenericTest1<Integer> to GenericTest1<Number>
How can it be fixed?

```
public class GenericTest1<T> {
    private T t;

    public GenericTest1(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void set(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T get() {
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericTest1<Integer> g = new GenericTest1<>(6);
        GenericTest1<Number> r = g; <==here
    }
}
```

Comment: Typecast it `GenericTest1<Number> r =(GenericTest1<Integer>) g; `

Comment: @ShashankKadne the type cast won't work - it still does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

The misconception here is that `GenericTest1<Number>` is a superclass of `GenericTest1<Integer>`. It isn't, so you have to cast each member individually.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common misunderstanding when it comes to programming with generics. Here two concrete   type `GenericTest1<Integer>` and `GenericTest1<Number>` has no relationship. The only common part is both are subclass of `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

The tow classes, GenericTest<Number> and GenericTest<Integer> are not assignment compatible. You can not even cast them. But, if you don't mind copying the object, you can do the following:

Add a copy constructor to your class:

```
public GenericTest1(GenericTest1<? extends T> other) {
    this.t = other.t;
}
```

And then copy the object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericTest1<Integer> g = new GenericTest1<>(6);
    GenericTest1<Number> r = new GenericTest1<Number>(g);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GenericTest1<Integer>` and `GenericTest1<Number>` are not compatible and you cannot cast between them! But if you don't want to expose Integer, you can use a bound:

```
GenericTest1<? extends Number> r = g;
```

`r` is a `GenericTest1<Integer>` in real, but the declaration allows access to Number only. Because of the unspecific type T, you cannot call `set()` (ok, works with null), but you can use `get()`:

```
g.set(Integer.valueOf(1)); // OK
r.set(Integer.valueOf(1)); // compile ERROR
if (r.get().intValue() == 1) { //OK
    ...  
}
```

Comment: By doing so, I get the compilation error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from GenericTest1<Integer> to GenericTest1<? extends Number>

Comment: Which Java Version do you use? No problem with Java 6 or 7. I have no Java 5 any more.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would limit acceptable types in your class and introduce method that compares the field with `Number` or with other `GenericNumber` and define your generic class like

```
public class GenericNumber<T extends Number> {
    private T number;
    public T getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(T number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public void setNumber(T number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    //constructors
    public int compareTo(Number n) throws Exception {
        if((number == null) || (n == null))
            throw new Exception("Can't compare null values");
        else if(number.doubleValue() > n.doubleValue)
            return 1;
        else if(number.doubleValue() == n.doubleValue)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
    public int compareTo(GenericNumber n) throws Exception {
        if(n == null)
            throw new Exception("Can't compare null values");
        return compateTo(n.getNumber());
    }
}
```

With this approach testing for equality of instances will transform into the following condition, with your objects: `(r.compareTo(g) == 0)`.

If you don't want to use the java-flavoured comparing class method of this type you can, of course, typecast the fields and compare with `=` operator.

For the behaviour you expect it is not right to make such an assignment because `GenericNumber<Integer>` is not a subtype of `GenericNumber<Number>`, as our intuition implies, though Integer is subtype of Number. To understand that suppose that in your case you would like to call a set method on an instance of `GenericNumber<Number>`:

```
GenericNumber<Integer> i = new GenericNumber<Integer>();
Integer ii = 3;
i.setNumber(ii);
GenericNumber<Number> n = i;//suppose it will be consumed by compiler
//in this case it will be tempting to forget about i and use n instead, like in the following lines
Folat f = 2.5f;
n.setNumber(f);
//would be valid because method signature will be 
//public void Number setNumber(Number number)
//but what actually happens is that you will try to call method of class
//GenericNumber<Integer> with signature public void Integer setNumber(Integer number)
```

As you see, the last line will cause an error, so you need to use generics with caution.

By the way, tutorial section on generics of then-Sun, now-Oracle site is worth visiting, namely:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html and/or
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html.